# Adding foreign keys in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, migration

I've just inherited a blog platform that uses Rails 3.2 (!!), and I'm looking to add some functionality. I have two models, `Article` and `Issue`, which I'd like to associate such that any `Issue` `has_many :articles` and and any `Article` `belongs_to :issue`.

I've looked into using the gem `foreigner` to help with this, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without adding more gems. I've looked around SO and seen some conflicting stuff. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041474/add-has-many-and-belongs-to-migration-from-command-line) seems to only apply to Rails 4, which I guess automatically generates this sort of migration.

Can I do this manually by migrating to create appropriate integer fields in both schemas, and then putting the `has_many` and `belong_to` statements in the models?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT: Rails 4

That's exactly what you should do: generate a migration for Article that adds the issue_id column:

```
$ rails g migration AddIssueToArticle issue:references
```

That'll generate a migration that will look like this, which will add the issue_id column and create an index:

```
class AddIssueToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :issue, index: true
  end
end
```

### Rails 3.2

```
$ rails g migration AddIssueIdToArticle issue_id:integer
```

Edit the generated migration and add an index:

```
class AddIssueIdToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :issue_id, :integer
    add_index :articles, :issue_id
  end
end
```

### Both versions:

Run the migration:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:test:prepare
```

And then add the relationship to the Article and Issue classes:

```
# ./app/models/article.rb
class Article
  belongs_to :issue
  # ... the rest of the class
end

# ./app/models/issue.rb
class Issue
  has_many :articles
  # ... the rest of the class
end
```

If your classes are namespaced or the integer column is a different name, then you'll need to add more data to the `belongs_to` and `has_many` method arguments.

See [the docs for 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration) (and [3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)) for more about generating migrations.

Comment: Oh! My answer will work for 4.0 projects. Editing now for better 3.2 support.

Comment: Running into a little trouble here.

When I ran `rails g migration AddIssueIdToArticle issue:references`, Rails 3.2 gave me the following migration:


    class AddIssueIdToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration

      def change

        add_column :articles, :issue, :references

      end

    end

Which is a little different from the above. When I tried `rake db:migrate`, I got a Postgres syntax error on `references` in `LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD COLUMN "issue" references`. I tried the migration you supplied above, but `add_reference` is not part of Rails 3.2.
Thoughts? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your solution for **Rails 3.2** does _not_ add a foreign key, just an index, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ecoologic look at the second section for 3.2, the migration has this: `add_column :articles, :issue_id, :integer` which adds the foreign key.

Comment: I think that's a regular index, not a _foreign key_ index??

Comment: pretty sure that a foreign key is just the primary id of another table. confused how your solution is different. activerecord should generate sql similar to yours from the migration created here

Comment: This solution does not add a foreign key, only an index. The solution by @ecoologic should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the snippet that I wrote to add multiple foreign keys in Rails 3.2

```
class ChangeAdminUsersEmployee < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      tables = %i[admin_users]
      reference = 'employee'

      tables.each do |table|
        p sql = <<-SQL
          ALTER TABLE `#{table}`
          ADD CONSTRAINT `#{table}_#{reference}_fk`
          FOREIGN KEY (`#{reference}_id`) REFERENCES `#{reference}s`(`id`);
        SQL

        p ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
        puts "===="
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```